# How to export the Data from the ContentNote Object in the Salesforce Professional Edition

Tags: data-loader, contentnote

I have exported all the data from the Professional edition Salesforce Org. However I have all the data from the available objects, but the data of the Salesforce Internal object 'ContentNote' is missing.

As the API is not enabled in this org, I cannot even query it in the Org.

If anyone know hows to export the ContentNote Data from the Salesforce Professional Edition Org, please guide me about it.

Comment: Did you export the data using the Scheduled Data Export feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to deal with the contentversion object as contentnote is missing in the backup files..Contentversion object has a field like 'textpreview' and 'title which holds the information.You will need to import the contentversion records.Secondly,export the just now imported contentversion  to get new contentdocumentid.Use this new contentdocumentid and mapped it with old contentdocument id using VLOOKUP's  and also use  title to import the contentdocumentlink.Like wise map the other fields which are required.Perform the update on contentdocumentlink.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform your export using the [Scheduled Data Export feature](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_exportdata.htm&type=5), make sure to select the `Include Salesforce Files and Salesforce CRM Content document versions` check box.

When you do so, your ZIP files will include all of the Content in your org. `ContentNote` is essentially a facade over the underlying `ContentDocument` and `ContentVersion` records. You'll find your Notes and their contents in the same location as other attached Files, in those objects.